# Magento 2 Get customer ID from session in a block class

Tags: magento2, customer

How to get customer ID from session? I tried this but not work.

```
protected $_customerBonusPointFactory;
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(Session $customerSession, \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function _prepareLayout() {
    var_dump($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
    exit();
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: If customer logged in then you can get customer id otherwise it's return null using '$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()'

Comment: I have logged in but it returns null. And I'm doing it in the block class.

Comment: Which session class you use?

Comment: I just found that `$this->session->isLoggedIn()` return true in my controller class but return false in my block class. Why?

Comment: Can you show your block class code? It's working fine here.

Comment: The above code in the question is my block class code.

Comment: Block has to be set `cacheable=false` see [Magento 2 - Get customer ID from session in a block class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/magento-2-get-customer-id-from-session-in-a-block-class)

Comment: **Be careful** using `cacheable=false` ! It will invalidated Full Page Cache (FPC) for every pages the block appears on. Performances will be affected. [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/163103/45441) are more informations about it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's working copy. You can compare with your block class. Here I use **Form** as block class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {

        var_dump($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
        exit();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly the same but it still return null. And `$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()` is false always. I do the same in a controller class and it works fine.

Comment: Finally, it works. I'm not sure what I have changed.

Comment: have you disabled full page cache maybe?

Comment: Yes it was cache I've had same issue `<block class="Vendor\Block\Bla\Bla" name="block.name" template="Wed2b_Suppliers::template/template.phtml" cacheable="false"/>`

Comment: I disabled cache still its returning null

Comment: for me its working fine after cacheable="false".

Comment: Thanks @JulianoVargas your solution worked!

Answer (score 11):

When You define block which use session You have to disable cache for it.

```
 <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="Name"
 template="Vendor_Module::template/path.phtml" cacheable="false">
 </block>
```

Comment: this will cause the whole page and every page that use this block will be MISSed by the FPC

Comment: @DoniWibowo that is true, but you need to be carefull when caching pages with dynamic data in the first place. You don't want to display the same name for all customers for example.

Comment: This is the best solution for me that I found but I don't really like it. Is there a way to cache it for each customer independently ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,` class to get customer ID from customer session.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

public function getCustomer()
{
    echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); //Print current customer ID

    $customerData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer(); 
    print_r($customerData->getData()); //Print current Customer Data
}
```

**NOTE**: You only get customer id if customer logged in and customer session initialized

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work when you pass the Context object to the parent class before instantiating the customer session :

```
class History extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $_session;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        array $data
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_session = $session;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {

        var_dump($this->_session->getCustomerId());
        exit();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd. I observe the same thing. Thank you for the help. I wonder why this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an instance in header.phtml file as below and also if more than one store is available and one wants to get mail in only one of the stores.

```
<?php
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
    $storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
?>

<?php
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); // get ID
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get the customer ID returning even with the cacheable attribute set to false.

What worked for me was using httpContext as explained in this article:
https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-get-customer-session-data-when-a-cache-is-enabled-in-magento-2/

Seems like the best solution as it doesn't require you to switch off caching.

Answer (score 0):

While we are injecting customer session in block to retrive logged in customer data and we are not getting customer data from block because Magento 2 reset all the customer sessions when FPC is enabled.

Please use cacheable="false" for bloick in your layout :

```
<referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Arman\Test\Block\List" name="list" template="Arman_Test::list.phtml" cacheable="false"> 
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

In this case, Magento 2 ignore this page from caching.

Comment: how to use cacheable="false" in cms pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the `customer_id` then without loading whole object (see method `getCustomer` method) you can get it by simply using `getCustomerId` method.

As `getId` method also calls `getCustomerId` method.

> file : vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Session.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve customer model object
 *
 * @return Customer
 * use getCustomerId() instead
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->_customerModel === null) {
        $this->_customerModel = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($this->getCustomerId());
    }

    return $this->_customerModel;
}


/**
 * Retrieve customer id from current session
 *
 * @api
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getCustomerId()
{
    if ($this->storage->getData('customer_id')) {
        return $this->storage->getData('customer_id');
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer id from current session
 *
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getCustomerId();
}
```