# Does setting a cacheable false on block invalidate full page cache for entire page?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I have heard this but I cannot confirm it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true, you can see it mentioned the Dev Docs too if you want extra confirmation :

> To create an uncacheable page, mark any block on that page as
>   uncacheable in the layout using cacheable="false".

You can see that on [this page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html).

Comment: So should this situation be avoided at all costs?

Comment: @LM_Fielding Unless you want to purposefully stop the whole page from being cached then yeah I would avoid. If you need to prevent one block from being cached take a look at hole punching methods.

Comment: I'm aware of hole punching methods, but thank you for the great tip! That is the reason I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.
Full page cache will not be used on that page.
But block cache and the rest works.

[Block with Cachable=false not rendered on product view page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/block-with-cachable-false-not-rendered-on-product-view-page)

Comment: Of note, FPC is often responsible for the majority of caching performance gains, so thinking 'oh I'm just disabling one cache out of like 12' is usually a bad idea.