# Get Data From Session

Tags: magento2

How we can get customer id form session if customer is login i use this code but not working:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
print_r($customerSession);
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
  echo "test".$customerSession->getCustomerId();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to not use ObjectManager directly.

You should be more specific about the problem instead of just saying it is not working. Like:
Where you are using this code?
Is there an error thrown?
Where is the code breaking? Is the customer session variable not getting printed?

You should use getData() with the object variable for debugging.
Your code looks correct other than the last line, it should be
getCustomer()->getId()

Try the accepted answer in the below question:
[Magento 2 - Get customer ID from session in a block class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/magento-2-get-customer-id-from-session-in-a-block-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn())
{
     echo "Customer Id = ".$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Please run this code. It will print the logged in customer id.