# Magento 2 - How to get logged in user email id using customer session

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account, magento2.2.6, customer-session

I'm using `Magento 2.2.6`, How can I get the email ID of logged in user to show in header.

Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/magento-2-get-customer-id-from-session-in-a-block-class 

Please check link and if you replace getId() with getEmail(), you will get email of logged in customer.

Comment: Is this for Email ID or User ID ?

Comment: You need to change getId() with getEmail() to get customer email. Here is one more example. http://www.blogtreat.com/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/

Comment: @user54226 add below code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create an instance in header.phtml file as below and also if more than one store is available and one wants to get mail in only one of the stores.

[image]

```
<?php
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
    $storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
?>

<?php
    $customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); // get Email
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I place it below the customer name in customer-welcome element.

Comment: [user54226](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54226/user54226) Answer edited.

Comment: @SHEESHRAM, why is there a screenshot of the code?

Comment: [Black](/users/66769/black) Code is also there, Please check.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, class to get customer ID from customer session. Try this code.

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

public function getCustomer()
{
    echo $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); //Print current customer ID

    $customerData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer(); 
    print_r($customerData->getData()); //Print current Customer Data
    echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerData->getId() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerData->getName() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerData->getEmail() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Group Id: ' . $customerData->getGroupId() . '<br/>';
}
```

**NOTE: You only get customer id if customer logged in and customer session initialized**