# How to get all orders in order history page magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, sales-order, order-history

I need to get all orders on the sales order history page without any limit I need to get the orders. In Magento 2.3.

I had tried the below code  using the OrderCollectionFactory but I am getting the error

```
if (!$this->orders) {

            $this->orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create($customerIds)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            );
            $this->orders->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ["sop" => "amt_sales_order_payment"],
                'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
                ['po_number']
            )
            ->where('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);
            
            $this->orders->setOrder(
            'ext_order_id',
            'desc'
            );
            
        }
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in
> /var/www/html/app/code/Sm/SalesOrderGridTable/Block/Order/History.php:139
> Stack trace: #0

Comment: where backend or frontend ? and please describe more.

Comment: At Frontend Bro Sales order History page.

Comment: @Msquare Did you got any solution for my question.

Comment: Please check and update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/VendoerName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" type="VendoerName\ModuleName\Block\Order\History" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoerName/ModuleName/Block/Order**

**History.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendoerName\ModuleName\Block\Order;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;

/**
 * Sales order history block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class History extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'VendoerName_ModuleName::order/history.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Orders'));
    }

    /**
     * Provide order collection factory
     *
     * @return CollectionFactoryInterface
     * @deprecated 100.1.1
     */
    private function getOrderCollectionFactory()
    {
        if ($this->orderCollectionFactory === null) {
            $this->orderCollectionFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactoryInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getAllOrder()
    {
        return $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get customer orders
     *
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getOrders()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                'sales.order.history.pager'
            )->setCollection(
                $this->getOrders()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getOrders()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Pager child block output
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    /**
     * Get order view URL
     *
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getViewUrl($order)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get order track URL
     *
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     * @deprecated 102.0.3 Action does not exist
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function getTrackUrl($order)
    {
        //phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        trigger_error('Method is deprecated', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Get reorder URL
     *
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReorderUrl($order)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('sales/order/reorder', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get customer account URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/account/');
    }

    /**
     * Get message for no orders.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     * @since 102.1.0
     */
    public function getEmptyOrdersMessage()
    {
        return __('You have placed no orders.');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Dolphin/AutoRelatedProducts/view/frontend/templates/order**

**history.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $block */
?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getAllOrder(); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)) : ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Orders')) ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?></th>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')) ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getRealOrderId()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra) : ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getStatusLabel()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewUrl($_order)) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View Order')) ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder::class)->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reorder')) ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getEmptyOrdersMessage()) ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

> **Update History.php getAllOrder() function**

```
public function getAllOrder()
{
    $cutId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
    $orderColl = [];
    if ($cutId) {
        $orderColl = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orderColl->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$cutId);
    }
    return $orderColl;
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: you can also filter data like this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-Load-all-Orders-for-Specified-Customer-ID/m-p/73657#M2645

Comment: yes i can get the point from your answer by i need to get all order order of the    logged in or customer id's which i need also with the filtes.

Comment: You need to get current customer id and  use addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',123456) to collection.

Comment: get current customer id try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171791/82670

Comment: if (!$this->orders) {

   $this->orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create($customerIds)->addFieldToSelect(
    '*'
   )->addFieldToFilter(
    'status',
    ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
   );
   $this->orders->getSelect()
   ->joinLeft(
    ["sop" => "amt_sales_order_payment"],
    'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
    ['po_number']
   )
   ->where('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);
   
   $this->orders->setOrder(
   'ext_order_id',
   'desc'
   );
  }

I had tried this please check wheather it will work
Getting this error

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Sm/SalesOrderGridTable/Block/Order/History.php:139 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Please update your question with your code. And add filter into this getAllOrder() function.

Comment: Updated the answer please check it.

Comment: Please check and upadate me.

Comment: When adding the ponumber filter how can i add in this updated result can you form an fucntion which iam had given as reference.