# Customer Session Dont work adequately

Tags: magento2, api, model, customer-session

i want to get customer id in model, but customer session return null in any case. Someone can help me ?

I also try to get customer id in block but doest work !

Comment: Max, can you add the code here to understand where you are trying to get customer id

Comment: Yes in the block when you get the customer ID, it won't work because most of the block files are cached , try following this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/magento-2-get-customer-id-from-session-in-a-block-class